# Jenkins not displaying test case stdout

Tags: junit, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to publish my test results from reports on jenkins. But i see that jenkins is not displaying the entire stdout. Only part of stdout is being displayed.

This is how one of my test case report looks like:

```
 <testcase classname="com.oracle.pgbu.rest.resources.navigation.NavigationHelperTest" name="printDocs(TestReporter)" time="0.13">
      <system-out><![CDATA[
unique-id: [engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.oracle.pgbu.rest.resources.navigation.NavigationHelperTest]/[method:printDocs(org.junit.jupiter.api.TestReporter)]
display-name: printDocs(TestReporter)
]]></system-out>

      <system-out><![CDATA[
Report Entry #1 (timestamp: 2018-12-17T19:13:00.767)
    - value: 

 ----- /primaveraadmin links and help items ----- 
Report Entry #2 (timestamp: 2018-12-17T19:13:00.77)
    - value: Application Administrators      (DocID: 85774)          

Report Entry #3 (timestamp: 2018-12-17T19:13:00.771)
    - value: License Usage                   (DocID: 81927)          

Report Entry #4 (timestamp: 2018-12-17T19:13:00.771)
    - value: System Announcements            (DocID: 84924)          

Report Entry #5 (timestamp: 2018-12-17T19:13:00.771)
    - value: System Settings                 (DocIDs: 81797 81802 102236 81804 89057 81806 81809 89894 81810 85775 81808 81811 89055 81793)
     </system-out>
</testcase>
```

I observe that only first nested part of system-out displayed on jenkins, but not the second part. This is how my jenkins file looks like:

```
 post {
       always {
           junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: 'reports/junit/*.xml,projects/pages/test-results/*.xml', 
        } 
      }
```

Is there anyway that i could fix this to display the entire stdout? Thanks

Comment: I am using Junit5 TestPublisher to record the stdout to reports

Answer (score 1):

Having more than one `system-out` per `testcase` is NOT against the schema:

```
 <xs:element ref="system-out" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/platform-tests/src/test/resources/jenkins-junit.xsd

This looks like a problem with Jenkins or its JUnit plugin. To be honest, I have never seen a JUnit report with more than one `system-out` per `testcase`, perhaps handling such an unpopular case wasn't implemented.